# How to keep alive context in Blazor Server (EF Core - dependency injection problem)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

The problem is when I want to use `DbContext`, it's telling me it is disposed.

I have a Blazor server app. I am using EF Core with dependency injection.

I register my `DbContext` and repository in DI:

```
services.AddScoped<GetwayRepository, GetwayRepository>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(option =>
        {
            option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Sms"));
        });
```

this is my GetwayRepository

```
public class GetwayRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public GetwayRepository(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public async Task<IEnumerable<GatewayDto>> GetAllGetway(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return await _context.Gateways.Select(g => new GatewayDto(
           g.Ip,
           g.UserName,
           g.Password, g.Lines!.Select(l => l.LineNumber)
           )).ToArrayAsync(token);
    }

   .....
    
   other functions
}
```

And I use the repo in parent and child

```
@inject GetwayRepository _repository
@layout AdminLayout
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
@page "/gateway"
<div class="flex flex-col">

    <div class="p-8">
        <TwButton ButtonText="Add Gatway" onclick="()=>showAddGatway = true"></TwButton>
    </div>
   
    <div>
        @if (dtos is null)
        {
            <TwSpinner></TwSpinner>
        }
        else
        {

            <GatewayGrid dtos="dtos"></GatewayGrid>
        }
    </div>
  

</div>

@if (showAddGatway){
    <TwModal   ModalHeader="Add Gateway">
        <AddGateway IsAdded="CloseModal"></AddGateway>
    </TwModal>
}
```

`Grid` and `AddGateway` are child components. In the child components, I get this exception

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
> Unhandled exception in circuit 'RPVfdtvIg3mVofKUWe8dySSR6SZ3YKs6UR3l-EHA1-E'.
>
> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

even i Use transient for regestring `DbContext` and  `GetwayRepository`
and it didnt work. also try  implement IDispose for my `GetwayRepository` and my component but get same Error

Comment: You don't. `DbContext` objects are intended to be short-lived.

Comment: Could you post `TwButton` component codes

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you're using the DBContext, so no one can provide any sort of detailed answer.  It's obviously being consumed in `GetwayRepository` somehow.  Search this site for "Blazor DbContextFactory" and see this MS Docs article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor.

Comment: DbContextFactory and its for i injected in my GetwayRepository  and implement Idispose for GetwayRepository   and change GetwayRepository  to transient

Comment: So the code is different from that in the question now? You should indeeed inject a factory, not a context.

Comment: You code above doesn't do `DbContextFactory`.  Your `GetwayRepository` injects a single context, not a factory.  Please read [and implement] the provided material.  You won't solve your problem by persisting in a single context!  I see no `Dispose` or `IDisposable` implementation, yet the error is pretty specific that you are doing it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For Blazor Server you need to use IDbContextFactory and in your repository you constructor inject it like this:

```cs
private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext> _dbContextFactory;

public GetwayRepository(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext> dbContextFactory)
{
   _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
}
```

and in your methods in the repository:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<GatewayDto>> GetAllGetway(CancellationToken token)
{
   using ApplicationContext context = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync(token);

   return await context.Gateways.Select(g => new GatewayDto(
      g.Ip,
      g.UserName,
      g.Password, 
      g.Lines!.Select(l => l.LineNumber)
      )).ToArrayAsync(token);
}
```

Now you should never encounter this context disposed exception.

PS. don't forget to configure your service collection in Program.cs like this:
`builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("YourContextKeyInAppsettings")`